# Google App Engine app_identity_defaultcredentialsbased_stub.py is returning a 'NoneType' for token.expires_in error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm running into a rather strange problem using Google App Engine. While trying to authorize my apps identity using GetAccessToken, I keep getting the error:

```
    ERROR    2018-03-08 18:14:42,472 api_server.py:364] Exception while handling app_identity_service.GetAccessToken()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 332, in _handle_POST
    api_response = _execute_request(request).Encode()
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 188, in _execute_request
    make_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 183, in make_request
    request_id)
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub.py", line 151, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity_defaultcredentialsbased_stub.py", line 200, in _Dynamic_GetAccessToken
    'expires': now + token.expires_in,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

From what I can see, Google is trying to concatenate 'now' which is an integer, with 'token.expires_in' which should also be an integer, but instead is returning as a 'NoneType' object. I am using Python 2.7 in this project for specific reasons, and am fully up to date with the Google Cloud SDK. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
-Josh Jackson

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the source code for the `get_access_token` method used in Python (which can be checked [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity#get_access_token)), and there is no reference to any object returned by the method called `expires_in`. However, as you can see in the code, it returns `expires_at`

Python recognizes `expires_in` as a NoneType because there is no object named as that in the token. Whenever you do your call to `token.expires_in`, change it to `token.expires_at` and test it again.